# Which io stream does this line of output go to with dstat

Tags: bash

When I run `dstat` from a kernel 2.6 CentOS 6 64 bit. I got the following output:

```
# sed -n '4p' <(dstat -dl --float --nocolor 1 1) | awk -F '|' '{print $1,$2}' | awk '{print $1,$2,$3}'
Module dstat_disk24old failed to load. (No suitable block devices found to monitor)
0 0.01 0
```

What's interesting is this line:

```
Module dstat_disk24old failed to load. (No suitable block devices found to monitor)
```

When I append `| grep -v failed` or `2> /dev/null`, it doesn't filter out this line. When I append `> a.txt`, this line also doesn't go to a.txt. So I'm wondering which stream this line goes to, even if it is printed on the screen?

Comment: Presumably standard error, file descriptor 2. That normally goes to the screen. You can check by redirecting it with `2> filename`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It went to standard error, which is default to file descriptor 2. While in `cmd1 | cmd2`, only standard out of `cmd1` was redirected to standard in of `cmd2`.

As a convention, all error and diagnostic messages will go to standard error.

You can use `strace` to confirm:

```
$ strace -e write dstat -dl --float --nocolor 1 1
write(2, "Module dstat_disk24old failed to"..., 83Module dstat_disk24old failed to load. (No suitable block devices found to monitor)) = 83
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
write(1, "\33[7l---load-avg---\n 1m   5m  15m"..., 34---load-avg---
 1m   5m  15m 
) = 34
write(1, "   0    0    0\n", 15   0    0    0
)        = 15
write(1, "   0    0    0\n", 15   0    0    0
)        = 15
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

You must redirect standard error to standard out if you want pipe to capture standard error output:

```
dstat -dl --float --nocolor 1 1 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks. I see. I tried to redirect the error to the black hole /dev/null, but I was too late. Looks like I should do it before the first |.

Answer (score 1):

This `>` file redirector works on standard out. Since you also said grep could not see it, have you considered it to be standard error? To confirm and capture if indeed it is stderr, try:

```
yourlongcommand 2> error.log
```

And examine error.log.